# Is there a "feature" in Open Liberty to connect to IBM MQ, equivalent to wmqJmsClient-2.0 in Liberty Profile?

Tags: ibm-mq, open-liberty

`IBM WebSphere Liberty Profile`provides the`"wmqJmsClient-2.0"`feature to interact with`IBM MQ`

Is there an equivalent for Open Liberty?

**[UPDATED]**

If not (as it seems), how to connect Open Liberty to IBM MQ?

Should I develop an Open Liberty "feature" equivalent of the one available in WLP, based on the IBM MQ official RAR file (currently `"9.1.0.0-IBM-MQ-Java-InstallRA.jar"`) ?

Or is there a "generic" way to configure such a connection in Open Liberty?

(I guess the question arises with other Queue Managers like ActiveMQ "Classic", ActiveMQ Artemis, OpenMQ, etc.)

Comment: no there is not

Comment: @AndyGuibert Could they just download the IBM MQ RA and use it with Open Liberty?

Comment: @AndyGuibert thanks

Comment: @JoshMc, I have the same question and I updated my post to add the question

Comment: @JoshMc In case the answer from njr isn't explicit enough yes you can use any JCA compliant resource adapter to integrate open liberty with a queue manager including IBM MQ.

Comment: @Alasdair, thanks for the reply, at the time I commented njr's answer was not posted yet.  Good information to know.  Also good to see 3 different IBM employee's responding about a Open Liberty question, you should let your ibm-mq counterparts know that more participation from them would also be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OpenLiberty has the jms-2.0 feature, which allows you to configure a JCA resource adapter which provides JMS such as the [WebSphere MQ resource adapter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031610_.htm).

Configuration in server.xml would be something like the following,

```
<server>
  <featureManager>
    <feature>jms-2.0</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
  </featureManager>

  <resourceAdapter id="wmqjmsra" location="C:/adapters/wmq/wmq.jmsra.rar"/>

  <jmsConnectionFactory jndiName="jms/cf1">
    <properties.wmqjmsra .../>
  </jmsConnectionFactory>

  ...
```

Comment: thanks. I will test it tomorrow and come back to approve your answer

Comment: it works. Thanks! On the minor side, in eclipse with WDT, the`server.xml`editor flags the`<properties.wmqjmsra ...`stanzas as`'properties.wmqjmsra ' is not a recognized configuration element.`. I don't know if there is a way to get rid of it.

Comment: One easy way to get the resource adaptor is to download it from Maven: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.mq/wmq.jmsra

Comment: To get this working in an Open Liberty docker container, I dropped the `wmq.jmsra.rar` file in `/liberty/wlp/shared/resources/wmq/JavaEE/`